# Where is TreeView.Nodes[int].Name in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, itemscollection

I'm working on a VB.NET to C# conversion and I'm currently stuck with a `TreeView` object.

```vb
Dim Arguments1 As String = path & "\" & fs & " ls " & TreeView1.Nodes(ccc).Name
```

So far, I can only get to this:

```
string Arguments1 = path + "\\" + fs + " ls " + ?
```

IN VB.NET, `TreeView` has a method, `Nodes(int)`, which I can get the `Name` property from. However, C# doesn't have a `Nodes(int)` method. I think it might be `TreeView1.Items[ccc]`, but `TreeView1.Items[ccc].Name` doesn't compile because the object `Items[int]` returns doesn't contains a `Name` property. How do I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you are translating code written for a *WinForms* `TreeView` that has a `Nodes` property with code for a *WPF* `TreeView` which has an `Items` property. You need to cast the returned value to a [`TreeViewItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem.aspx) to get the `Name` property. Your C# code will then be:

```
string Arguments1 = path + "\\" + fs + " ls " + ((TreeViewItem)TreeView1.Items[ccc]).Name
```